# Worker/Controller multi-threading and interface class

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, interface, qthread

Implemented as it seems to me an interface class for multithreaded objects. Everything works, except this line, when the window is closed.

```
connect(_controller, &IClass::finished, this, [] { qDebug() << "finished"; });
```

1. Do I reinvent the wheel?
2. Why is the `Controller::finished` signal not emitted when the object is deleted (when the window is closed)?
3. Is it possible to make signals private not to create a `Private Controller`?
4. Do I need to make the controller a descendant of `IClass`?
5. Tips and suggestions

code example:

## mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
class Worker1;
class Worker2;


class IClass : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    IClass(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
public:
    enum class Types { Worker1, Worker2, };
    static IClass* CreateInstance(Types t, QObject *parent = nullptr);
signals:
    void started();
    void finished();
public slots:
    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2(int i) = 0;
    virtual void f3(int x, double y) = 0;
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
};

class PrivateController : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    IClass *_w;
public:
    PrivateController(IClass *c, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), _w(c) {
        connect(this, &PrivateController::f1, _w, &IClass::f1);
        connect(this, &PrivateController::f2, _w, &IClass::f2);
        connect(this, &PrivateController::f3, _w, &IClass::f3);
        connect(this, &PrivateController::stop, _w, &IClass::stop);
    }
    ~PrivateController() override;
    void callF1()                   { emit f1(); }
    void callF2(int i)              { emit f2(i); }
    void callF3(int x, double y)    { emit f3(x, y); }
    void callStop()                 { emit stop(); }
signals:
    void f1();
    void f2(int i);
    void f3(int x, double y);

    
    void stop();
};

class Controller : public IClass {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller(IClass::Types t, QObject *parent = nullptr)
                        : IClass(parent), _w(CreateInstance(t)), _signals(_w) {
        connect(_w, &IClass::started, this, &IClass::started);
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, this, &IClass::finished);
    }
    ~Controller() override;
public slots:
    void f1() override                  { _signals.f1(); }
    void f2(int i) override             { _signals.f2(i); }
    void f3(int x, double y) override   { _signals.f3(x, y); }
    void start() override {
        QThread *th = new QThread;
        _w->moveToThread(th);
        connect(th, &QThread::started, _w, &IClass::start);
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, th, &QThread::quit);
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, th, &QThread::deleteLater);
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, _w, &IClass::deleteLater);
        th->start();
        qDebug() << "Controller::start";
    }
    void stop() override {
        _signals.stop();
        qDebug() << "Controller::stop";
    }
protected:
    IClass *_w;
    PrivateController _signals;
};

class Worker1 : public IClass {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker1(QObject *parent = nullptr)
                        : IClass(parent) {
        // some code
    }
public slots:
    void f1() override {
        qDebug() << "Worker1::f1";
    }
    void f2(int i) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker1::f2" << i;
    }
    void f3(int x, double y) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker1::f3" << x << y;
    }
    void start() override {
        emit started();
        qDebug() << "Worker1::start";
    }
    void stop() override {
        emit finished();
        qDebug() << "Worker1::stop";
    }
protected:
    // some code
};

class Worker2 : public IClass {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker2(QObject *parent = nullptr)
                        : IClass(parent) {
        // some code
    }
public slots:
    void f1() override {
        qDebug() << "Worker2::f1";
    }
    void f2(int i) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker2::f2" << i;
    }
    void f3(int x, double y) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker2::f3" << x << y;
    }
    void start() override {
        emit started();
        qDebug() << "Worker2::start";
    }
    void stop() override {
        emit finished();
        qDebug() << "Worker2::stop";
    }
protected:
    // some code
};

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    IClass *_controller;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

## mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _controller(new Controller(IClass::Types::Worker2, this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(_controller, &IClass::started, this, [] { qDebug() << "started"; });
    connect(_controller, &IClass::finished, this, [] { qDebug() << "finished"; });
    _controller->start();
    _controller->f1();
    _controller->f2(2);
    _controller->f3(3, 4.4);
//    _controller->stop();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }

PrivateController::~PrivateController() { qDebug() << "~PrivateController()"; }

IClass *IClass::CreateInstance(IClass::Types t, QObject *parent) {
    switch(t) {
    case Types::Worker1: { return new Worker1(parent); }
    case Types::Worker2: { return new Worker2(parent); }
    }
}

Controller::~Controller() { _signals.callStop(); }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Controller::start
Worker2::start
Worker2::f1
Worker2::f2 2
Worker2::f3 3 4.4
started
~PrivateController()
Worker2::stop
```

Don't emited `finished`.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking it, where are you 'forwarding' and emitting the finished() signal from your IClass?

Comment: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40378-QThread-doesn-t-emit-finished()-signal-when-quit()-or-exit()-slots-are-called

Answer (score 3):

About question #2: try this edit to your `main`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    int r = a.exec();

    qDebug() << "event loop gone ...";

    return r;
}
```

Check your output, now. As you can see, when the `finished` signal is emitted, your main thread hasn't an event loop anymore, so the signal won't be caught (because it's coming from the other thread).

To prove it further, add a push button to the window and have a `clicked` slot like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    _controller->stop();
    qApp->processEvents();
    qApp->exit();
}
```

This way you exit the app, but only after all queued events got processed (i.e. the queued signal gets delivered ...).

About everything else you ask, frankly: it's seems quite broad even for a bounty question. Anyway, hope I have helped a bit.

Comment: call `on_pushButton_clicked` so work, but i don't understand, why `Controller::~Controller() { _signals.callStop(); QCoreApplication::processEvents(); }` don't work. Why main thread hasn't an event loop, if i just call destructor `MainWindow`, but not a `qApp->exit();`. Why is the destructor completes, do not perform `processEvent`?

Comment: When the destructor gets called, the event loop has gone already, and subsequent calls to processEvents have no meaning anymore. Whenever you close (even hide) the **last** top level widget in your qt app, the event loop stops automatically, without calling `exit`. Keep in mind that `MainWindow` destructor gets called **after** `Qapplication::exec` returns, when the `MainWindow` instance goes out of scope, i.e. when exiting the `main` function block.